# Issue with date conversion - using jS F, Y

Tags: php, date, strtotime

Hopefully someone can answer this.

Running this piece of code:

```
$date = "2nd January, 2013"; 
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date));
```

Which returns:

```
2012-01-02.
```

Which clearly is not correct (or at least the results i'm hoping for)

Now based on some online research, this may possibly be passing it as time, rather then year. Is there a way to manage this, or do you have to supply dates in an american format for it to return correctly?

Comment: so what you hoping for ? its fine and suppose to do what it is doing

Comment: I'm hoping for:
2013-01-02.

Ie: the 2nd of January, 2013.

it's returning 2012. not 2013.

Comment: Interesting. Reproduced on my PHP 5.3.10 and on [codepad](http://codepad.org/2PURfVwR).

Comment: Glad it's not just me! i even tried specifically setting the timezone, thinking it may alter how it treats entered date formats, but didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to PHP's [acceptable date string format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php), comma is only acceptable in **Textual month, day and year** format: `m ([ .\t-])* dd [,.stndrh\t ]+ y`

So you'll have to either switch the position of month and day, or get rid of the comma:

```php
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime("2nd January, 2013")); //outputs "2012-01-02"
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime("2nd January 2013")); //outputs "2013-01-02"
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime("January 2nd, 2013")); //outputs "2013-01-02"
```

[codepad paste](http://codepad.org/cOflYyd0)

I **guess** the reason the first statement returns 2012 is because characters after the comma are ignored, so the string is actually treated as `2nd January`, and the current year is then assumed.

Comment: Thanks for this you are correct, it's a shame because it links the possible layouts for dates, but i guess nothing is perfect.

Comment: The characters after the comma are not ignored, the `2013` is interpreted as a time in `Hi` format to give 8:13pm. As such, the date string (according to PHP) has no year value specified so the current year is used.